# Solving $y' - \frac{2y}{x}= 1$

Tags: integration

I've been trying to solve this integration problem for a while, and I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Am I solving this correctly? Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Isn't the actual problem cut off?

Comment: The problem is y' - 2y/x = 1

Comment: OK but what are you supposed to do with it and what is your work showing?

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please write the equations in the text of your answer, don't post images as they make it more difficult to find this question should the same issue arise for someone else. Here is a [MathJax help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Are you trying to find the general solution?

Comment: Yes i am trying to find the general solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It's homogeneous function so simply put $y=vx$

or Calculate Integrating factor
$$e^{\int{{-2} \over x}dx}={1 \over x^2}$$
Now multiply your equation with I.F.
$$y'({1 \over x^2})-\frac{2y}{x^3}={1 \over x^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}({y \over x^2})={1 \over x^2}$$

Can you take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$y=ux$$ we get $$y'=u'x+u$$ then we get
$$u'x-u=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your constant of integration $k$ is part of the integral, so it should also be divided by the integrating factor.